# Store JSON file in angular assets folder from node server

Tags: node.js, json, angular

I need to update JSON file, which is store in angular assets folder. To achieve this, I tried to pass the JSON file to my backend server (nodejs) and there retrieve it, update it and send it back to angular assets folder. I managed to get the file without any problem (so processing should not be too complicated), but I can not return it to the assets folder . I have tried to make a post but it seems that it is not even done... I also tried with the request library but it returns a 404 when I put the corresponding URL...

```
var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 4200,
    path: '/assets/i18n',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  };

  var req = http.get("http://localhost:4200/assets/i18n/es.json", function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function (data) {
        var JSONObject = JSON.parse(data)

        var httpreq = http.request(options, function (response) {
          response.setEncoding('utf8');
          response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log("body: " + chunk);
          });
          response.on('end', function() {
            res.send('ok');
          })
        });
    });
  });
```

Comment: you mean to update json file which is located at angular  from backend which has nodejs?

Comment: Yes, I need to update a JSON file that is hosted in angular

Comment: Directly you cannot update json file so you can  keep that json object in any component and update as soon as you received response from API